# How to install svnmucc on Amazon Linux?

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, svn, amazon-linux

I have an AWS Linux machine running Amazon Linux:

Linux XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX 4.4.30-32.54.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Nov 10 15:52:05 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

And I am trying to install "svnmucc"

But "yum install subversion" does not install it and I don't find how to install it except by compiling the sources of subversion which I don't want to do.

It looks like it is available on some other Linux distributions so it should be possible on this distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find out whether it is available at all by asking yum to provide information on what package contains a given pathname (which can contain wildcards). For example:

```
yum whatprovides */svnmucc
```

This is done this way so that it will match /usr/sbin/svnmucc and /usr/bin/svnmucc and any other possible dirname.

If the distribution provides it, this command will display information about which package contains it.

For AWS , it would give:

> yum install subversion-tools